# Meaning of "affectionate abandon"

Tags: idioms

> You should treat your book with **affectionate abandon**.

In this sentence what does *affectionate abandon* mean? Is there an abandon that is affectionate?

Answer (score 2):

Here *[abandon](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/abandon_2)* is a noun meaning an uncontrolled way of behaving that shows you don't care what others think. Hence *affectionate abandon* refers to uncontrolled feelings of fondness for the book.

Comment: I am asking about the meaning as whole of the expression.

Comment: Affectionate is an adjective used to describe someone who shows fondness and tenderness. Does this adjective go with the word abandon?

Comment: The answer is clear now :). Sorry I am not an English native speaker, for this my questions seem strange.

Comment: It does if you'd allow a similar use of "abandon" in the more common expression, "wild abandon"...as in this example: **"The freshman senator kissed his aide, under cover of a parking garage, with *wild abandon*"**. In that usage, "abandon" is synonymous with "recklessness".